# $postLink not called in angular 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs

Given the following:

```
var Panda;
(function (Panda) {
    "use strict";
    var BulkCaptureComponentController = (function () {
        function BulkCaptureComponentController() {
            this.textBinding = '';
            this.dataBinding = 0;
        }
        BulkCaptureComponentController.prototype.$onInit = function () {
            console.log('init');
        };
        BulkCaptureComponentController.prototype.$postLink = function () {
            alert('1');
        };
        BulkCaptureComponentController.prototype.add = function () {
            this.functionBinding();
        };
        return BulkCaptureComponentController;
    }());
    var BulkCaptureController = (function () {
        function BulkCaptureController() {
            this.value = 0;
        }
        BulkCaptureController.prototype.$postLink = function () {
            alert('1');
        };
        BulkCaptureController.prototype.$onInit = function () {
            console.log('init');
        };
        BulkCaptureController.prototype.add = function () {
            this.value = this.value + 1;
        };
        return BulkCaptureController;
    }());
    var BulkCaptureComponent = (function () {
        function BulkCaptureComponent() {
            this.bindings = {
                textBinding: '@',
                dataBinding: '<',
                functionBinding: '&'
            };
            this.controller = BulkCaptureComponentController;
            this.templateUrl = '/areas/schedule/views/bulkcapture/bulk-capture.html';
        }
        return BulkCaptureComponent;
    }());
    Panda.panda.component('bulkCaptureComponent', new BulkCaptureComponent());
    Panda.panda.controller("BulkCaptureController", BulkCaptureController);
})(Panda || (Panda = {}));
;
```

Why is `$postLink` never called by angular.

My template (for now) just contains html content.
Both `init` methods work perfectly, but `$postLink` is not called.

Comment: What version are you using? $postLink was landed in 1.5.3.

Comment: version 1.5.2, lucky me!
thanks for that - please post it as the answer and I will very happily accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some new lifecycle hooks (including $postLink) [were added](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/CHANGELOG.md#153-diplohaplontic-meiosis-2016-03-25) in Angular 1.5.3

- `$onChanges(changesObj)` - Called whenever one-way bindings are updated. The `changesObj` is a hash whose keys
  are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form
  `{ currentValue: ..., previousValue: ... }`. Use this hook to trigger updates within a component such as
  cloning the bound value to prevent accidental mutation of the outer value.
- `$onDestroy` - Called on a controller when its containing scope is destroyed. Use this hook for releasing
  external resources, watches and event handlers.
- `$postLink` - Called after this controller's element and its children been linked. Similar to the post-link
  function this hook can be used to set up DOM event handlers and do direct DOM manipulation.
  Note that child elements that contain `templateUrl` directives will not have been compiled and linked since
  they are waiting for their template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been
  suspended until that occurs.

They are not available in previous 1.5.x versions.